# split .csv file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a huge csv file with more columns than allowed in excel so i need to split the file into 2 in order to use it.

I found a code which i can put in a batch file and it works too but the problem is if data is not available in a cell it takes data from the next available cell.
Also it is taking a long time.
Please let me know how the code can be edited?

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM Edit this value to change the name of the file that needs splitting. Include the extension.
SET BFN=BigFile.csv
REM Edit this value to change the number of lines per file.
SET LPF=5000
REM Edit this value to change the name of each short file. It will be followed by a number indicating where it is in the list.
SET SFN=SplitFile

REM Do not change beyond this line.

SET SFX=%BFN:~-3%

SET /A LineNum=0
SET /A FileNum=1

For /F "delims==" %%l in (%BFN%) Do (
    SET /A LineNum+=1

    echo %%l >> %SFN%!FileNum!.%SFX%

    if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
        SET /A LineNum=0
        SET /A FileNum+=1
    )
)
endlocal
Pause
```

Also my company does not allow me to download any csv splitters or any other data. 
All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your data contain any "commas within quotes" ?

Comment: Are you confusing Columns with Rows?  I do not see you splitting the columns apart.  Is your data really delimited by a "=" sign?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply my data is comma delimited. This was a code i found online posted by someone whose data was = delimited. My data does not contain commas within quotes. Please let me know if you have the answer to this.

Comment: Yes and i am sorry i mentioned columns instead of rows.